# Where is the tutorial "processor" generated?

Tags: php, thrift

I just started working with the github hosted build of apache thrift, I am basically interested in a java client and PHP server implementation, but for now i am using the php server and client only

All nice and easy i made my thrift file

```
namespace php mobiledata

struct sms
{
    1: string from,
    2: string to,
    3: string smstext,
    4: string smsdatetime,
    5: string smsdirection
}

struct smsdetails
{
    1: list<sms> smsdata
}

service mobiledataservice
{
    void insertsmsdata (1: smsdetails smslist)
}
```

And I generated the gen-php folder, which has got Types.php and mobiledataservice.php

the basic sample that comes with the github for php as server shows a line of code 
$handler = new CalculatorHandler();
$processor = new \tutorial\CalculatorProcessor($handler);

I can't find this class "CalculatorProcessor" and certainly I don't have a comparative class generated in my gen_php like mobiledataprocessor, and it baffles me as to how I would run my server in absence of processor.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, there's something wrong. Could you please file a JIRA ticket about it?

Comment: filed it https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2519

Comment: The tutorial is incomplete, I modified the ticket accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server code is generated by calling

```
thrift -r  -gen php:server  tutorial.thrift
```

Note the `:server` part after `-gen php`, this triggers the processor generation.

These are all PHP options available:

```
php (PHP):
  inlined:         Generate PHP inlined files
  server:          Generate PHP server stubs
  oop:             Generate PHP with object oriented subclasses
  rest:            Generate PHP REST processors
```